# Return unique values without removing duplicates - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates, unique

I know there are many answers about returning unique values in an array after removing duplicates, but isn't every element in an array unique after you remove the duplicates? I want to only return values that are unique prior to removing any duplicates. If the element repeats in the original array, I don't want it in my final array.

So this array...

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

should return only:

```
[0, 2, 4]
```

Another way to phrase this would be to remove all duplicates as well as all unique values that were ever duplicates.

I'm coming from a JavaScript background and am still a little shaky with C# syntax. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use LINQ, grouping by the value, counting the number of elements in each group, and then returning the keys for groups with a single value:

```
var singleOccurrences = array.GroupBy(x => x)
                             .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                             .Select(g => g.Key)
                             .ToArray();
```

If you really need this to be efficient for large inputs, you could write your own method keeping track of "elements with a single value" and "elements with more than one value" as sets. I'd start with this though :)

Comment: Thanks man! The inputs will be limited to 50 or so values - probably still small enough to not suffer any efficiency issues.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `GroupBy` method

```
var uniqueNumbers = numbers.GroupBy(x => x)
                   .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                   .Select(g => g.Key)
                   .ToArray();
```

This will basically group all the numbers and then take those group that has one number in it.

Comment: Faster reply by just a hair :) Thanks!