# How to remove an element from an array WITHOUT removing duplicates. in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates

I needed to remove the first element from an array in my program. Here is the code:

```
input = input.Except(new string[] {input[0]}).ToArray();
```

This returns the difference between the original array and an array with the to be removed element. However, it also removes duplicates (I think).

When I input

```
average 10 20 10 30
```

it returns

```
10 20 30
```

Job done, but I don't want it to remove duplicates. How do I get it to stop removing duplicates?

Comment: I do realize that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287686/return-unique-values-without-removing-duplicates-c-sharp?rq=1) is a simalar question. Oops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I needed to remove the first element from an array in my program.

Instead of using LINQ [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx), you could use [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) instead:

> Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns the remaining elements.

```
input = input.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input variable has the type of List, you should be able to use:

```
input.Remove(input[0])
```

Remove will remove the first matching element it finds in the list.